# Where can older revisions of the HTML5 specification be found?

Tags: html, diff, specifications

I'm having trouble finding older revisions of the HTML5 specification. I keep finding resources such as [WHATWG's version](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/), or [HTML5 differences from HTML4](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5-diff/) and my google-fu is failing me.

Is there a repo where I can browse different versions of the HTML5 spec, and (*more importantly*) compare different versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how far back you want to go, but for looking at earlier versions a couple of options spring to mind.

The [latest version](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/index.html) of the spec has a list of links to some previous drafts at the very start.

The other option is the [Wayback Machine](http://wayback.archive.org/web/%2a/http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/), but it seems it stopped indexing the pages mid-2011.

Don't know how you'd go about comparing them though. You might be better looking at the [diff tracker](http://html5.org/tools/web-apps-tracker) although that's tracking changes on the WHATWG version.

Comment: Not sure how I managed to overlook the "Previous Versions" header at the top of the spec. Thanks!